# Wordpress if post or blog category statement

Tags: wordpress, post, categories

got a little problem here on Wordpress.

I am trying to use PHP to check whether the page I am on is a category page or a post page if it isn't on either it will do something else nothing.

The code I have is:

```
<?php if( (!is_category($category)) || (!is_single($post)) ) { ?>

Do something...

<?php } ?>
```

When I try it without the or the category bit works fine. When I join them together the code stops working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're actually trying to test is if it's not a category **and** not a post. So change your condition accordingly:

```
if( (!is_category($category)) && (!is_single($post)) ) {
```